# How to underline TextView in some items of a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, and it's item's data come from a table in my database.I want underline one of the TextViews in item if the "span"column is true.
How can i get it? someone tell me to use SpannableString,but how to link the SpannableString with listView?
My adapter is like this:

```
public void UpdataAdpter(){
    Cursor cur= listsDbAdapter.fetchAllData(tableName);
    if(cur!=null&& cur.getCount()>=0){
    adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.dolist_item,
                cur,
                new String[]{yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_NAME,yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_PRICESTR,yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_NUMSTR},
                new int[]{R.id.doList_itemname,R.id.doList_itemPrice,R.id.doList_itemNum}
        );
        doListlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom adapter to do this. Read http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/category/android-tutorials/cursoradapter-tutorials/